# /act_{account-id}/adcreatives creative_ids parameter is not working in the Facebook Ads Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I have an application that uses the Facebook Ads OLD REST API and recently I heard that it will be deprecated in a month, so I'm working hard to migrate all my code to the new Graph API...
Unfortunately, nothing goes smoothly.

when calling to **GET /act_{account-id}/adcreatives** to get the AdCreatives for a specific campaign the parameter **creative_ids** is not working and always retrieving all the creative for the account!
This was working fine in the rest api... and no documentation changes were made in ads.getCreatives so I'm assuming **creative_ids** paramter is still there...

Any help will be appreciated!
thanks,
Yaniv Hakim

Answer (score 0):

I found the **_ids** parameters to be finicky so I use the generic **ids=comma-separated list** parameter, without the act_{account-id}. Creative IDS are unique across accounts so there's no need to specify the account-id. If you want to use the specific parameters, have you tried creative_id, creativeids, creativeid and other permutations you can think of (with and without account-id)?